# How to hide passwords on Jenkins console output?

Tags: jenkins, credentials

I have a job to be triggered by developers where they have to put their AD's before triggering build. But thoes passwords are displayed on console output. I have tried mask passwords plugin. But the problem is I cannot store all developers AD's in job configuration.

Please suggest me any solution.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand this question. What exactly do you mean by _have to put their AD's before triggering build_? Do you use job parameters? Do you use the Credentials system? Is the password an input to some other command?

Comment: They put their AD's as password parameters to trigger deployment job.

Comment: By AD are you referring to Active Directory? In other words, they need to specify their own Active Directory credentials for the deployment step. I can certainly see why you would want to mask that!

Answer (score 1):

Please find below my findings with solution [without using Mask Passwords plugin]:

**Brief Description about my jenkins job:**
I wrote a job which downloads the artifacts from Nexus based on the parameters given at run-time and then makes a Database SQL connection and deploy the SQL scripts using maven flyway plugin. My job takes - Environment, Database Schema, Artifact version number, Flyway command, Database User and it's password as input parameters.

**Brief Background about problem:**
While passing the PASSWORD as MAVEN GOAL (Parameter), it was coming in Jenkins Console as a plain text.
Although I was using "Password Parameter" to pass the password at run-time but then also it was coming as plain text in console.

I tried to use the "secret text" to encrypt the password but then my job started failing because the encrypted password was getting passed to Maven Goals, which was not able to connect to DB.

**Solution:**

I used ***"Inject passwords to the build as environment variables"*** from Build Environment and defined its value as my "password parameter" (my password parameter name was db_password) which I am passing as parameter at run-time (eg.: I defined my inject password value as : ${db_password}  ).

And this is working as expected. The password which I am passing while running my job is coming as [*******]

> [console log:
>   Executing Maven:  -B -f /work/jenkins_data/workspace/S2/database-deployment-via-flyway-EDOS/pom.xml clean compile -Ddb=UAT_cms_core -DdatabaseSchema=cms-core -Dmode=info -DdeploymentVersion=1.2.9 -Ddb_user=DB_USER -Ddb_password=[*******]
>   ]

Regards,
Rohit Rajpoot

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer I just came across in the [Jenkins documentation](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs):

> Normally you will start your script with
>
> ```
> set +x
> ```
>
> so that commands you run are not echoed to the log, in case you
>   mention the values of secrets in those commands.

Comment: I am using maven where I provide my credentials in application pom.xml